# Single Core: Couldn't you slow down a program by moving your mouse a lot?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I'm learning about Concurrency and how the OS handles interrupts such as moving your cursor across the screen while a program is doing some important computation like large matrix multiplications.

My question is, say you're on those old computers with a single core on it, wouldn't that single core need to constantly context-switch to handle your interrupts because of all the cursor moving and therefore more time is needed for the important computation? But I assume it's not that huge of a delay because perhaps the OS will prioritize my calculation above my interrupts? Maybe skip a few frames between the movement.

And if we move to a multi-core system, is this generally less likely to happen as the cursor moving will probably be processed by another core? So my calculations will not really be that delayed?

While I am at this, am I right to assume that the single-core computer probably goes through like hundreds of processes and it context-switches throughout all of them? So quite literally, your computer is doing one instruction at a time for a certain amount of time (a time slice) and then it needs to switch to another process with a different set of instructions. If so, it's amazing how the core does so much.... Jump, get the context, do a few steps, save the context onto stack, jump yet again. Rinse and repeat. There's obviously no parallelism. So no two instructions are EVER running at the same time. It only gives that illusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last paragraph is correct, it's the job of the operating system's scheduler to generate the feeling of parallelism by letting each process execute some instructions and then continuing with the next. This does not only affect single core CPUs by the way - typically your computer will be running many more processes than you have CPUs. (Use task manager on windows or top on Linux to see how many processes are running currently).

In terms of your mouse question: that interrupt will most likely just change the current mouse coordinates in a variable and not cause a repaint. Therefore it is going to be extremely fast and should not cause any measurable delay in programming execution. Maybe it would if you could move your mouse by the speed of light ;)

Comment: Thanks for verifying this. Another question. What if... the computer is like a server. Is it actually possible that perhaps there are so many client requests coming to the sever constantly that the matrix multiplication calculation is almost ignored? Like it's being pushed into the background so much because of the constant new incoming interrupts? Almost like a teacher that has new kids is asking at him/her with so much questions that the teacher is able to do her tasks like taking attendance? Thank you.

Comment: that depends a lot on what the programs that do run are doing. If you would run 10 programs in parallell that are computationally intense, then every program would run 10 times slower (programs are CPU bound - meaning that the CPU is their bottleneck).

However please keep in mind that many programs interact with the hardddisk or network (IO bound) which is very slow compared to CPUs. so while a program is waiting to read a file, the CPU is idle and will be assigned to other processes that need it more.